Basemap Robinson Projection Map Border Cut Off on Left and Right Edges
I'm using Basemap to plot a global contour on a Robinson map projection, and I've noticed an aesthetic issue that has been bothering me. In every example I've come across using the Basemap Robinson projection, the border on the left and right edges is cut off in the middle. I circled what I'm talking about in the PNG below and included the code to recreate it directly from the Basemap Robinson documentation. Any suggestions for how to make the border an even width all the way around would be greatly appreciated! Cheers

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# lon_0 is central longitude of projection.
# resolution = 'c' means use crude resolution coastlines.
m = Basemap(projection='robin',lon_0=0,resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
# draw parallels and meridians.
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,120.,30.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,360.,60.))
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua') 
plt.title("Robinson Projection")
plt.show()

